# MATLAB: Undefined function 'isfinite' for input arguments of type 'cell'

Tags: matlab, pie-chart

I am pretty new to MATLAB. I want to make a pie chart of a dataset which contains categorical data:

```
 ?                      1836 
 Federal-gov             960 
 Local-gov              2093 
 Never-worked              7 
 Private               22696 
 Self-emp-inc           1116 
 Self-emp-not-inc       2541 
 State-gov              1297 
 Without-pay              14
```

I imported dataset whose size is 32561x1 and i converted it into categorical data using:

```
w = categorical(w)
```

now when i use the pie command in matlab:

```
pie(w)
```

it gives me the following error:

```
Undefined function 'isfinite' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
Error in pie (line 34)
if ~all(isfinite(x))
```

I am not understanding is my dataset too big for this pie chart? what can i do to generate a pie chart for this big categorical data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `w` a cell array?

Comment: w is categorical array. It was a cell array before I converted it to categorical array.

Comment: @David That's the original cause of the failure. However, looking at [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/plot-categorical-data.html) Mathworks example, I don't see why the output of `categorical` couldn't be fed into `pie` (in fact, that's what the example seems to be doing)

Comment: It's hard to say much without seeing what your `w` really is, does this simple example work? `A={'first' 'second' 'third' 'fourth' 'fifth'},B=randi(5,20,1),C={A{B}}.',C=categorical(C),pie(C)`

Comment: @David I tried inputting the example you gave and its still giving the same error. I wonder how will it  work. I double-checked my variable w, it is showing value in the workplace as:

    workclass      32561x1 categorical

Comment: It works just fine for me, what version of Matlab are you using? (I'm using 2015a)

Comment: I'm using 2014a. I'll look into the documentation of it. Thanks @David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The categorical data type in **2014a** didn't have support it does now (generally due to newness). In more recent versions you can pass the **categorical** array to `pie` directly. In **2014a** passing the category counts will work, as any numeric array would. This is simple to do with the `countcats` function. While the `categories` function can return the category names as strings to use for labelling.

using the test case given by David in comments

```
A={'first' 'second' 'third' 'fourth' 'fifth'};
B=randi(5,20,1);
C={A{B}}.';                                     %'
C=categorical(C);
```

you can just call

```
pie(countcats(C))
```

and to include the labels:

```
pie(countcats(C),categories(C))
```